# mongodb integer index precision

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

**TLDR: Given documents such as `{ x: 15, y: 15 }`, can I create an index on `20 / x, 20 / y` without adding those values as fields?**

I'd like to index the x, y coordinates of a collection of documents.  However my use case is such that:

- Each document will have a unique x,y pair, so you can think of this as an ID.
- Documents are added in blocks of 20x20 and are always fully populated (every x,y combo in that block will exists)
- Lookups will only ever be against blocks of 20x20 and will always align on those boundaries.  I'll never query for part of a block or for values that aren't multiples of 20.
- For any possible block, there will either be no data or 4,000 results.  A block is never sparsely populated.
- I will be writing much more frequently than reading so write efficiency is very important.

An index of `{ x: 1, y: 1}` would work but seems wasteful. With my use case the index would have an entry for every document in the collection! Since my queries will be aligned on multiples of 20, I really only need to index to that resolution.  I'm expecting this would produce a smaller footprint on disk, in memory, and slightly faster lookups.

Is there a way to create an index like this or am I thinking in the wrong direction?

I'm aware that I could add `block_x` and `block_y` to my document, but the block concept doesn't exist in my application so it would be junk data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since my queries will be aligned on multiples of 20, I really only need to index to that resolution. I'm expecting this would produce a smaller footprint on disk, in memory, and slightly faster lookups.

Index entries are created per-document, since each index entry points to a single document. Lowering the "resolution" of the index would therefore impart no space savings at all, since the size of the index depends on the index type (single field, compound, etc. see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#index-types) and the number of documents in that collection.

> I'm aware that I could add block_x and block_y to my document, but the block concept doesn't exist in my application so it would be junk data.

If the fields `block_x` and `block_y` would help you to more effectively find a document, then I wouldn't say it's junk data. It's true that you don't need to display those fields in your application, but they could be useful to speed up your queries nonetheless.

Comment: I was under the impression (from a pluralsight guide to mondgodb) that indexes were stored as a map of key (indexed value) to an array of matching document pointers, so I thought by reducing the number of keys I could speed up lookups.  After reading your comment, it sounds like I was trying to solve a non-issue.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Glad to help. I would appreciate it if you can mark it as answered.